# Syntax for a one-line infinite detached loop

Tags: bash, loops

I could run something in endless loop like this:

```
$ while true; do foo; done
```

I could run something detached like this:

```
$ foo &
```

But I can't run something detached in endless loop like this:

```
$ while true; do foo & ; done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

How to run an infinite detached loop in one line of shell code?

Answer (score 2):

`&` is a terminator like `;`, you can't mix them. Just use

```
while : ; do foo & done
```

I'd add a `sleep` somehwere, otherwise you'll quickly flood your system.

Answer (score 2):

You should clarify whether you want

- many copies of foo running in the background or
- a single copy of foo running within a backgrounded while loop.

[choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba)'s answer will do the former.  To do the latter you can use subshell syntax:

```
(while true; do foo; done) &
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the loop in the background, rather than each individual `foo` command, you can put the whole thing in parentheses:

```
( while true; do foo; done ) &
```

Answer (score 0):

All good answers here already - just be aware that your original loop with @choroba's correction will successfully make a very messy infinite string of processes spawned in quick succession.

Note that there are several useful variants. You could throw a delay inside the loop like this -

```
while true; do sleep 1 && date & done
```

But that won't cause any delay between processes spawned. Consider something more like this:

```
echo 0 > cond   # false
delay=10        # secs
```

then

```
until (( $(<cond) )) do; sleep $delay && foo & done
```

or

```
while sleep $delay; do (( $(<cond) )) || foo & done
```

then make sure `foo` sets cond to 1 when you want it to stop spawning.

But I'd try for a more controlled approach, like

```
until foo; do sleep $delay; done &
```

That runs `foo` in the foreground OF a loop running in background, so to speak, and only tries again until `foo` exits cleanly.

You get the idea.